# Не вставлять родителя в таблицу при сохранении ребенка JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, entity, eclipselink

У меня есть 2 класса:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT")
public class Client {    
    private String clientNo;
    private String clientName;
}
    
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENT_COMM")
public class ClientCommision {
    private int id;
        
    private Client client;
            
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CLIENT_NO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    public Client getClient() {
       return client;
    }
}
```

Когда я выполняю `EntityManager.merge(clientCommission)` с полем `client`, у которого `clientNo` отсутствует в таблице `CLIENT` (например, 11111), то JPA автоматически сохраняет новую запись в таблицу `CLIENT` с номером 11111.

Как мне реализовать так, чтобы если `client` с таким номером отсутствует в таблице `CLIENT`, то JPA не пытался сохранить его в таблицу `CLIENT`? (На базе данных ссылки на поле `CLIENT_NO` из таблицы `CLIENT_COMM` нет, то есть если руками это сделать, то сохраняется нормально).

Comment: а если в @JoinColumn попробовать использовать ссылку на столбец в Client referencedColumnName = "clientNo"?

в этот ответе:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244569/what-is-referencedcolumnname-used-for-in-jpa
поподробнее описывают предназначение  этого параметра, возможно Вам может подойти